# YouTube Data API v3: upload video processing abandoned

Tags: java, spring-boot, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I tried to upload a video to YouTube using the YouTube Data API v3. When I upload the video, it shows uploading started. Then it stays 0% for about 3 minutes. After that error message is showing that processing was abandoned.

[This](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video) is the documentation I am following. And also am using Spring Boot to do this.

This error comes as output:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the video file you uploaded has *a valid video content*. In other words, can you play OK (without error) in a video player your local video file?

Comment: On the other hand, your post is contradictory in itself: (1) you indicate as base an official doc that has sample code written in *Python*, while (2) you say you're implementing video uploading in *Java*. Please post your Java code.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code. Is your application verified?

Comment: Thanks everyone. i fixed my issue. the issue is length of media content is invalid